# Customer Provider in Keycloak - a REST call with jakarta.ws.rs

Tags: jax-rs, keycloak, quarkus

Inital I was building a custom provider, where a custom mapper did a REST call to a third party api  while the user was identify by ADFS (Identity Provider).
After the Upgrade to the quarkus distro of keycloak (22.0.1) I switched dependencies from javax to jakarta.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven Build successful but if the call should happen, keycloak gets this error.

*Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider for jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder cannot be found*

I tried to switch dependencies, switched packages back to javax (no build possible).

**Solved:**
Took the SimpleHttp from Keycloak to realise the rest call.

Answer (score 0):

Got it with the SimpleHttp client from keycloak repo

```
...

SimpleHttp.Response response = SimpleHttp.doGet(url, httpClient).param("email", userAttribute).asResponse();
// Check response status
if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
   throw new ClientRemoteMapperException("Wrong status received for remote claim - Expected: 200, Received: " + response.getStatus(), url);
}
return response.asJson();
```